# Grails URL mapping to always show www.mysite.com in browser address bar

Tags: grails

I have grails application which has several controllers and actions. Suppose
a user goes to:

http://  www.mysite.com/user/register

which means action register in controller user is executed. what I want is that when the response is received by the browser ( or when the request is made by the browser), the browser URL bar should display (the root path):
http:// www.mysite.com

without executing the default action and controller (mapped to the root path '/' in the URLMappings.groovy).

Is this possible and how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either redirect to root controller+action:

```
redirect controller: "home", action: "index"
```

(though this *will* call the action, is it that you're trying to aviod?)
or call

```
render template:'some_template', model: '[some: model]'
```

for root page. It will work if you extract root page elements to a template and have a simple model in it. We, for instance, have no model at all for a root page.

If you wish to always stay on root page, you'll have to use `redirect`: how can browser go from action page to root page without being told to?
I believe you can use `params` property of [redirect method, or flash variable](http://www.grails.org/Controller+Dynamic+Methods), to tell the root action what to do and what not to do.